# jssor slider error in bullet navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

hi i use jssor slider for making a slider in ebay template this is the first time i'm using it. so i'm just making a practice locally. the slider is working fine but when i add the bullet navigator it shows the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Navigator item prototype not defined.
```

here is my code so far...

```
 <script src="jssor.js"></script>
  <script src="jssor.slider.js"></script>
  <script>
      jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
       var options = {

           $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,
            $ChanceToShow: 2
        }
    };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
  };
</script>
</head>
 <body>
   <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height:   300px;">

    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="blue.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="purple.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="red.jpg" /></div>
    </div>

  <!--navication bullets-->
    <div u="navigator" class="jssorb01">
      1
   </div>

    <div u="navigator" class="jssorb01">
     2
    </div>

    <div u="navigator" class="jssorb01">
      3
    </div>
      <!--/navigation bullets-->
      <!-- Trigger -->
      <script>jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');</script>
     </div>
```

and please give an example of how to use it in ebay listing template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download jssor.slider.fullpack.zip, unzip it and find 'skin\bullet-01.source.html'.

The bullet navigator skin looks like,

```
<!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
<!-- jssor slider bullet navigator skin 01 -->
<style>
    /*
    .jssorb01 div           (normal)
    .jssorb01 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
    .jssorb01 .av           (active)
    .jssorb01 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
    .jssorb01 .dn           (mousedown)
    */
    .jssorb01 div, .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av
    {
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        opacity: .7;
        overflow:hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: #000 1px solid;
    }
    .jssorb01 div { background-color: gray; }
    .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av:hover { background-color: #d3d3d3; }
    .jssorb01 .av { background-color: #fff; }
    .jssorb01 .dn, .jssorb01 .dn:hover { background-color: #555555; }
</style>
<!-- bullet navigator container -->
<div u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; right: 10px;">
    <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
    <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 12px; HEIGHT: 12px;"></div>
</div>
<!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->
```

Comment: hi also can you show how to use this slider in ebay, a script. i'm actaully confused about how to load the slider when it is in ebay template..

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Professional-Slideshow-Simple-HTML-Designs-eBay-Store-Auction-Listing-Templates-/221449031401?ssPageName=STRK:MESE:IT